# Oracle 11g default username and password to start sqlplus

Tags: oracle11g

I have installed Oracle 11g (latest version 11.2.0.1.0) on my system(Linux). During the installation, it didn't ask me to set a username or any password. I'm unable to start sqlplus because I don't have the username and password.
Can anyone tell me what is the default username and password or what is the default password for SYS or SYSTEM?

I have referred this "[What username & password should be entered when connecting to SQL*Plus after installing Oracle 11g?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722302/what-username-password-should-be-entered-when-connecting-to-sqlplus-after-ins)" but my problem is not resolved.

Comment: The installer **will** ask you for the passwords during installation - unless you installed it with a response file. In that case the passwords are stored in your response file.

Comment: No I am sure they didn't asked any username or password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once upon a time, there were predefined users and their passwords (system/manager and sys/change_on_install).

What you should do now, is to log on to your computer as user who owns Oracle software and - on the operating system command prompt - run

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

You'll be connected to the database, and then you can modify anyone's password, using

```
alter user any_username identified by its_password;
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-install the 11g, and see every installing step , it will ask to set password for SYSTEM/SYS , enter the new password, proceed to install it.  Then hit win+R, type sqlplus, run it, it go with with username, password.